# CSS - How to make a relative element follow me up and down but not left and right?

Tags: jquery, css, css-float

I have a parent div with a fixed position and inside of that div I have the main div with a relative position. While I scroll the bar up and down it follows me (this I want) but I don't want it to follow me when I scroll the bar left to right (or right to left).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="icons">
      icons
   </div>
</div
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 155px;
}
#icons  {
    width: 42px;
    position: relative;
    left: -67px;
}
```

**Thank you!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have to changed the `left` value of `#wrapper` based off of its initial position and the current `$(document).scrollLeft()` value:

```
var initSL = $(document).scrollLeft(),
    initOL = $('#wrapper').offset().left;

$(document).scroll(function(e){
    $('#wrapper').css('left', initOL - ($(document).scrollLeft() - initSL));
});
```

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/z52qG/1/)

Comment: Oh man, you've saved me so much time and headaches with this. Thanks a lot, you rock!

Comment: Hi, for some reason it works well on that jsfiddle site but it doesn't in Chrome. I copied all the code in a new html file. Are there other options with jQuery? Thanks again.

Comment: I built that fiddle in Chrome, so not sure why it wouldn't be working.  If you mean when you put that code on your page I wouldn't be able to say without seeing the specific situation, but you might need to specify an outer wrapper or something.

Comment: Thanks for coming back. :) I've put a test page on my site. http://test.sopranowebdesign.com/float-extra/

Comment: You're getting an error because you're loading the script before the DOM is ready.  You have to wrap the jQuery in a `$(function() { // code in answer });` so that it waits for the DOM to be ready.  See http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 2):

No need to get JS or jQuery involved. I slightly modified the former answer to use only html and css

Position:fixed;

http://jsfiddle.net/z52qG/11/

Comment: By the way mVChr, that is an awesome little tool you linked to!