# jQuery & CSS - How to stop a relative element from floating left and right (when you're scrolling)?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I'm sorry for posting this for a [second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643096/css-how-to-make-a-relative-element-follow-me-up-and-down-but-not-left-and-right) but I need a jQuery solution. The [original solution](http://jsfiddle.net/z52qG/1/) doesn't work in Chrome but works on the jsFiddle site (even when opened in Chrome).

Here are the details again:
I have a parent div with a fixed position and inside of that div I have the main div with a relative position. While I scroll the bar up and down it follows me (this I want) but I don't want it to follow me when I scroll the bar left to right (or right to left).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="icons">
      icons
   </div>
</div
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 155px;
}
#icons  {
    width: 42px;
    position: relative;
    left: -67px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
    var initSL = $(window).scrollLeft();
var initOL = $('#wrapper').offset().left;

$(window).scroll(function () { 
      $('#wrapper').css('left', initOL - ($(window).scrollLeft() - initSL));
})(jQuery);
```

**Thank you once again!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){
    $('#wrapper').css('left', initOL - ($(document).scrollLeft() - initSL + ' px'));
});
```

The jQuery .css function sets the css values as strings.

The scroll values you retreive from $(document).scrollLeft() are in pixels.

Comment: how so? i tested it in jsFiddle, on chrome and it worked.
try it yourself on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jJrvr/)